# Adding attributes to the core search block form

Tags: search, block-editor, forms

I'm trying to minimally hook (via a plugin) into the search form generated by the default search block and add a `target="_blank"` to open the results in a new tab. I'd much prefer to do this via PHP and not JavaScript. The `get_search_form` filter and outright overriding a piece of the template won't necessarily work because I can't assume the search experience hasn't been edited, only that the default core search block is being used and that it has some kind of search form. Is there some obvious use of `has_block` or `get_block_template` or some other newer function that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

The render_block filter might provide a solution.
I say 'might' because i have not tested and the search "form" element may not be accessible via the filter.

[Wordpress Render Block filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/)